# WiX: Registering Service with start parameter

Tags: service, wix, windows-installer

I need to register a Windows service with WiX installer that requires a (constant) parameter to start ("-r").

I can not find a way to specify this in ServiceInstall - any recommendation how to deal with this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the -r is to register the service, ServiceInstall can't use it; instead, you specify all the registration with ServiceInstall attributes. If the -r is to run the service, use the Arguments attribute.